# Collect css from class into array, give to another class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have two sets of elements, both with the same number of elements. I'm wondering how do I collect the width from the first set (width is variable) and then give it to the second set in the same order it was collected.

```
<div class="a">This element might have a width of 100px</div>
<div class="a">..while this one might be 50px</div>
<div class="a">..and this one is maybe 75px</div>
```

Collect into an array [100,50,75] and then pass it to another set of elements.

```
<div class="b">give me the 100px width</div>
<div class="b">and me the 50px width</div>
<div class="b">and me the 75px width</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick

```
$('.a').each(function(index) {
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    $('.b').eq(index).width(thisWidth);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jn6ns/)

Comment: Lol didn't get it at first. Your fiddle might've been clearer if you added `.a, .b {border: 1px solid red;}`